# Vue: Embed child element in a parent element that is marked with the v-html directive

Tags: vue.js

I want to embed/place a child element inside a parent element that is marked with the `v-html` directive. This is what I have now and it's clearly incorrect:

```
<span v-for="(word, index) in words" :key="index" v-html="word">
  <span>test</span>
</span>
```

`<span>test</span>` is NOT being rendered to the DOM.

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `v-html` attribute will override the content with what was provided, which is why your span element is not being rendered.

You will need to prepend/append your content to the variable that was passed into the v-html attribute or move it to a different node.

For example:

```
<span v-for="(word, index) in words" :key="index" v-html="word + '<span>test</span>'"></span>
```

or

```
var word = "something"
...
word += "<span>test</span>"

<span v-for="(word, index) in words" :key="index" v-html="word"></span>
```

or

```
<span v-for="(word, index) in words" :key="index">
  <span>test</span>
  <span v-html="word"></span>
</span>
```

Comment: The third answer is the cleanest IMHO